# TFS 2010 Missing Team Members in Iteration Backlog Workbook Capacity and Interruptions sheets

Tags: tfs, agile

We are using TFS 2010 and the MSF for Agile Software Development v5.0 template.

On opening the Iteration Backlog.xlsm Excel sheet we find that not all the team members are listed in the Capacity or the Interruptions sheets.

What lists do these tabs read from and how should I update them

[I have all the team members setup properly under the relevant project in Team Explorer]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for them to appear, they need to have been assigned to at least one Task within the given iteration.
The easiest way to achieve that is to do so in the "Iteration Backlog" worksheet. If at a later point you remove the team - member's assignment from all Tasks he/she shall remain in the "Interruptions"/"Capacity" sheets, but with a data validation error warning in the cell containing the name.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. The user though has a task assigned to the relevant iteration and does appear on the Iteration Backlog sheet in the Iteration Backlog workbook but still does not appear in the Capacity and Interruptions sheets I'm afraid.

Comment: Are you sure? The iteration is set in the "Settings" sheet. That is the one that has to match with the results of your query / your team members

Comment: Something funny is happening here - when I changed to a different iteration for testing the iteration that we are interested in disappeared in the "Settings" Sheet - so may be the problem is in the fact that I'm unable to see the iterations and not that Team Members are not appearing. Once fixed your original answer should solve the issue

Comment: You have a Backlog query, which returns some results. TFS populates the candidate values for Iteration ComboBox @ Settings from the results of your query. If all the WIs contained in the Backlog don't have a Iteration - setting, ComboBox shall remain empty.

Comment: Marking it as an answer as you pointed me in the right direction. The workbook was pointing to an earlier test iteration and I had not noted this. Thanks for your help, appreciate it - Liam